# How to set English(UK) as a default language in CKEditor 3.2

Tags: php, ckeditor

How to set English(UK) as a default language in CKEditor 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add it in your configuration file as:

```
config.defaultLanguage = 'en-gb';
```

Comment: can you post the lines from your configuration files?

Comment: Actually i want to set default spellchecker language is English UK. It is done written the code in config.js.

config.scayt_defLan = 'en_GB';
config.scayt_sLang  = 'en_GB';

Thanks Narcisradu for helping me.

Comment: @Sanjay - Then maybe you can accept my answer :). The question was not about configuring spellchecker. Try to post clear questions in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the language via config.defaultLanguage = 'en-gb'; just works, if the "user interface language" is not set.

Try: "config.language = 'en-gb';"

See: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.language